# How to get an send an embed depending on the users input

Tags: python, discord.py

Alright so I am trying to create a command that varies depending on what the user inputs. For example the user types "!peakrating" and then the bot responds with "what is your id". Then depending on what the users responds with after the embed will send something different. Here is the code I tried that didn't work.

```
@client.command()
async def peakrating(ctx, msg):
    ctx.send("What is your id")
    id = msg
    url = f"https://api.brawlhalla.com/player/{id}/ranked?api_key=MY_API_KEY"
    r = requests.get(url)
    udata = r.json()
    upeakrating = udata['peak_rating']

    premb = discord.Embed(title="PeakRating")
    premb.add_field(name="Your peak elo", value=f"{upeakrating}")

    await ctx.send(embed=premb)
```

Here is the error that follows the code above "discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: msg is a required argument that is missing."

Comment: So what did not work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: The error I get with the code above is "discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: msg is a required argument that is missing."

Comment: That is because you provided `msg` as an required argument. Also in the third line you didn't await the send method. If you await the third line and run the command like this `!peakrating <id>` it should work fine.

Comment: Yup I was just using it wrong, thank you!

Comment: Also another thing. You shouldn't be using requests in an asynchronous function. It is blocking. You should use aiohttp instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

The `def check` is like a terminal input

```
import asyncio


@client.command()
async def peakrating(ctx):
    try:
        def check(message):
            return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel 
        id = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=60, check=check) 
        # the member have 60 seconds to answer, you can change it if you want to

        url = f"https://api.brawlhalla.com/player/{id}/ranked? 
        api_key=MY_API_KEY"
        r = requests.get(url)
        udata = r.json()
        upeakrating = udata['peak_rating']

        premb = discord.Embed(title="PeakRating")
        premb.add_field(name="Your peak elo", value=f"{upeakrating}")
        await ctx.send(embed=premb)

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return await ctx.send('You did take so long, try again!')
```

But if you don't want a timeout, you need to:

- Remove the `import asyncio`
- Remove the `timeout=60` on `client.wait_for` function
- Replace the `except` stuff for this:

  ```
    except:
        return
  ```

And this should work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@client.command()
async def peakrating(ctx, id=None):
    if not id:
        await ctx.send("What is your id?")
        return
    url = f"https://api.brawlhalla.com/player/{id}/ranked? 
    api_key=MY_API_KEY"
    r = requests.get(url)
    udata = r.json()
    upeakrating = udata['peak_rating']
    premb = discord.Embed(title="PeakRating")
    premb.add_field(name="Your peak elo", value=f"{upeakrating}")
    await ctx.send(embed=premb)
```

Also you forgot to put await on your first message that you send.